# Issue with NumberFormat in ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, excel-interop, xlsx, xps-generation

I have a table of data (calculation results) that the user should be able to export to different formats. I use `Interop.Excel` to prepare a table with the data and use the data and format it using visual formatting (fonts, colors etc.) and `NumberFormat`. Example:

```
cellRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0";
```

When I save the table as an **Excel** file all formatting is ok when exporting to **.xlsx** and **.xls**:

```
excelWorkBook.SaveAs(exportFileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook); // for .xlsx
excelWorkBook.SaveAs(exportFileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8); // for .xls
```

I also want to give the user the possibility to export this table to **.pdf** and **.xps** from the application without having to open the Excel file. As I have prepared the tables in `Interop.Excel`, I tried exporting the same table to those file formats:

```
excelWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,exportFileName); // for .pdf
excelWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypeXPS,exportFileName); // for .xps
```

Both of these result in good documents except that all `NumberFormats` are lost resulting in long decimal values of doubles. This is not appropriate for the customer's summary of the data. (Colors and fonts remain as defined in **.pdf** and **.xps**.)

I have tried setting `.Style`and `.Styles` to `"Number"` or the like. This does not solve the problem.

I have also tried to protect the `Range` of cells or the `excelWorkSheet`. This does not solve the problem either.

Someone suggested calling a **VBA macro / sub** through **C#** but after some looking into that, I get the impression that it's not a very straight forward (or stable) path.

I am looking for any help in resolving this issue through `Interop.Excel` or in another way.

lucn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing it seems clear that the property I named in my comment must be set to `false`:
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = false;`

It is not evident why this influences the export to other formats such as `*.pdf`but this is clearly the case and setting the `.DisplayFormulas = false` solves the issue.

Hope this helps somebody.